# How to pass values in java to Query cassnadra database

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, cassandra

I am running cassandra database on a cloud. I have created a Rest web service to query the cassandra Db. I want to take input from the user who will be using the UI of my web service

Following is the code that i run:

```
public String cql2(int psa)
    {
        Cluster.Builder clusterBuilder = Cluster.builder()
                .addContactPoints("52.36.24.246").withPort(9042)
                .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setFetchSize(2000))
                .withCredentials("username", "password");
        Session session = clusterBuilder.build().connect();
        String cqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM godfather.crime WHERE           psa='"+psa+"' ALLOW FILTERING";
        for (Row row : session.execute(cqlStatement))
        {
            cql=(row.toString());
        }
        return cql;
    }
}
```

Comment: enter code here has been bimistakely typed in while formatting. Sorry abou that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general when a query is meant to be executed many times through the life of the application (with or without different parameters), prepared statements are the optimal solution.

Basically your code will become:

```
public class MyService {
    private Cluster cluster;
    private Session session;
    private PreparedStatement query;

     // exception handling not included to keep the code short
    public void init() {
        cluster = Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPoints("52.36.24.246").withPort(9042)
            .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setFetchSize(2000))
            .withCredentials("username", "password")
            .build();
        session = cluster.connect();
        query = session.prepare("SELECT * FROM godfather.crime WHERE psa= ?");
    }

    public String execQuery(int psa) {
        for(Row r : session.execute(prepared.bind(psa))) {
            // your processing here
        }
    }
```

}

A couple of additional details:

1. it is recommended to initialize the `Cluster` and `Session` only once per application. These are long lived objects that should be kept around.
2. it is recommended to prepare statements only once
3. things like exception handling, initialization, etc are not included in the code above for keeping it simple.

If you want to learn more about prepare statements:

1. Cassandra, as other databases, does support prepared statements. You can read more about the advantages of prepared statements on this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)
2. Prepared statements in Cassandra are very well documented in [Prepared statements in the Java driver for Cassandra](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/statements/prepared/)